# SAS EG how to stop a do loop after a function runs/fix results

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I am currently trying to loop a coalesce function in EG using macro language. The issue I'm having is the loop is populating all empty columns, rather than just the first empty cell. I have tried a form of if logic to stop the loop but not successfully and also tried and failed to fix the results after by comparing if the adjacent columns are the same and then deleting. I would like the loop to only populate the first empty cell as I need to run a 2nd coalesce loop with a 2nd variable afterwards. The attached image shows what results I am getting and what I am aiming for.

My current working code is as follows:

```
%macro coal;
data want;
set have;
%do i = 1 %to 5;
coal&i = coalescec(&column&i, var1);
%end;
run;
%mend;
```

[image: current results]

[image: output wanted]

Comment: Please post data as text, not photographs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An array loop, to find the first empty column, exit the loop, and populate that column with var1 :

```
data want ;
  set have ;
  array c{*} column: ;
  /* loop over array and find first empty column */
  cmiss = . ;
  do i = 1 to dim(c) until (cmiss) ;
    if missing(c{i}) then cmiss = i ;
  end ;
  if cmiss then c{cmiss} = var1 ;
  drop i ;
run ;
```

Comment: This has worked thank you Chris.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this entirely within a data step. If you want to constantly update the dataset and have it fill in values one by one, you can use arrays.

Example data:

```
data have;
    column1 = 123;
    column2 = 456;
    call missing(of column3-column5);
run;
```

Code:

```
data have;
    set have;
    array column[*] column:;

    /* Count non-missing columns */
    do i = 1 to dim(column);
        if(NOT missing(column[i]) ) then nonmiss+1;
            else leave;
    end;

    if(nonmiss < dim(column) ) then offset+1;

    do i = 1 to dim(column);
        if(missing(column[i]) ) then do;
            column[i] = column[offset];
            leave;
        end;
    end;

    drop i nonmiss;
run;
```

First step:

```
column1 column2 column3 column4 column5 offset
123     456     123     .      .        1
```

Second step:

```
column1 column2 column3 column4 column5 offset
123     456     123     456     .       2
```

Note that if you run this again it will pull the value from `column3` into `column5`.

Comment: I've just realised I made a mistake, var1 is a seperate column not a repeat of col 1. So 5 columns with the 6th being the variable I am coalescing with. Each row has a different number of missing columns. I have edited the post.